# Object key not populated as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

Please see the object structure below. I am trying to compare each date with a fixed array of the 30 min half hour intervals in a day and then create a new object where "handled" is summed by

1. Weekday
2. Half Hour interval

The below does properly map to the correct interval in the "hhObj" BUT it is only getting aggregated per half hour and then repeated for each "weekDay".

//Main Object array I want to build

```
var hhObj = [];
```

// Fixed array of all half hour intervals in a day

```
var halfHours = ["00:00", "00:30", "01:00", "01:30", "02:00", "02:30", "03:00", "03:30", "04:00", "04:30", "05:00", "05:30", "06:00", "06:30", "07:00", "07:30", "08:00", "08:30", "09:00", "09:30", "10:00", "10:30", "11:00", "11:30", "12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30", "15:00", "15:30", "16:00", "16:30", "17:00", "17:30", "18:00", "18:30", "19:00", "19:30", "20:00", "20:30", "21:00", "21:30", "22:00", "22:30", "23:00", "23:30"]
```

//Creating objects with key-pair-values for each half hour interval

```
  var intervalObj = [];

  for (i = 0; i < halfHours.length; i++) {
    intervalObj.push({
        interval: halfHours[i],
        answered: 0,
        handled: 0
    })
  }
```

// Adding the above interval objects to each weekday object

```
  for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    hhObj.push({
            day: i,
            data: intervalObj
    })
  }
```

// Object to extract data from

```
  var test = [
{"DateTime":"5/1/18 03:00:00 AM","Answered":"0","handled":"3"},
{"DateTime":"5/3/18 10:00:00 AM","Answered":"0","handled":"1"},
{"DateTime":"5/2/18 07:00:00 AM","Answered":"0","handled":"25"},
{"DateTime":"5/5/18 12:00:00 AM","Answered":"0","handled":"2"},
{"DateTime":"5/10/18 12:00:00 AM","Answered":"0","handled":"6"},
{"DateTime":"5/12/18 07:00:00 AM","Answered":"0","handled":"1"},
{"DateTime":"5/13/18 12:00:00 AM","Answered":"0","handled":"12"},
{"DateTime":"5/1/18 07:00:00 AM","Answered":"0","handled":"5"},
{"DateTime":"5/6/18 10:00:00 AM","Answered":"0","handled":"1"},
{"DateTime":"5/7/18 12:00:00 AM","Answered":"0","handled":"2"},
{"DateTime":"5/3/18 12:00:00 AM","Answered":"0","handled":"0"},
{"DateTime":"5/18/18 06:00:00 AM","Answered":"0","handled":"14"},
{"DateTime":"5/12/18 12:30:00 AM","Answered":"0","handled":"1"}]


    for (row in test) {
        var dt = test[row].DateTime;
            dt = new Date(dt)
        var weekDay = parseInt(dt.getDay());
        let hh = dt.getHours();
        if(hh < 10) {
            hh = '0' + hh
        }
        let mm = dt.getMinutes();
        if(mm == 0) {
            mm = '0' + mm;
        }

        var timeInterval = hh + ':' + mm;
        var answered = parseInt(test[row].CallsAnswered);
        var handled = parseInt(test[row].handled);
```

> The below logic is what fails. I have tried printing "idx" and "int"
>   which is the indexes for each object array, and I am getting the
>   correct results. Trying to map the correct weekday (hhObj[idx]) and
>   interval (hhObj[idx].data[int]) does not work.

```
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for(int in hhObj[i].data) {

            if(weekDay == hhObj[i].day && hhObj[i].data[int].interval == timeInterval) {

                var idx = parseInt(hhObj[i].day) - 1;

                hhObj[idx].data[int].handled += parseInt(test[row].handled);                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Expected structure:

```
hhObj = [{
    day: 1,
    data: [{
        interval: "00:00",
        handled: 10
    },
    {
        interval: "00:30",
        handled: 5
    }....]
},
{
    day: 2,
    data: [{
        interval: "00:00",
        handled: 2
    },
    {
        interval: "00:30",
        handled: 0
    }....]
}....]
```

Current result (Handled gets summed but replicated for the same interval across all weekdays):

```
hhObj = [{
    day: 1,
    data: [{
        interval: "00:00",
        handled: 12
    },
    {
        interval: "00:30",
        handled: 5
    }....]
},
{
    day: 2,
    data: [{
        interval: "00:00",
        handled: 12
    },
    {
        interval: "00:30",
        handled: 5
    }....]
}....]
```

Comment: Could you please clarify a bit what exactly you want? I had a look at it and have no real clue what you expect to be the result. Maybe you can give some more information :-)

Comment: I added the expected output to the code above